Trying to return a single value from MYSQL to Java but getting 0.0
If I run this query in MYSQL to get the time taken for the last query:
SELECT sum(Duration)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROFILING
WHERE QUERY_ID = (SELECT MAX(QUERY_ID) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROFILING);
I get a valid single result:
Result:
However, when i run the same query from Java I get zero results back:
    try {
        String sql = "SELECT SUM(Duration) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROFILING WHERE QUERY_ID =             (SELECT MAX(QUERY_ID) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROFILING)";
        Connection myCon2 = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PW);
        PreparedStatement myStmt = myCon2.prepareStatement(sql);
        ResultSet rs = myStmt.executeQuery(sql);
        while (rs.next()){
            System.out.println(rs.getDouble(1));
        }
    }
    catch ( SQLException e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

I have tried changing datatypes using and a stored procedure all to no avail. The code doesn't throw an exception it just retunrs O or null depending on which datatype I convert it to?

Post text rather than images wherever you can.

0.0 != 0.000773

Note that the prepared statement does not need executeQuery(sql), just executeQuery() as it already has sql

Make the following small change to the while () loop.
        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println(rs.getDouble("SUM(Duration)"));
        }

Also, just before ending the try { ... } block, close all the objects that have been created.
        // Close the objects
        rs.close();
        myStmt.close();
        myCon2.close();

    } // this is the end of try { ... } block

    catch ( SQLException e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


neither do address the problem in question

@user85421 Can you please elaborate?

the problem apparently is "but getting 0.0" instead of "0.000773" (see posted image) - 1) getDouble("SUM(Duration"), as suggested in your answer, will return the same as getDouble(1) from question; 2) closing the objects will not change the result at all (maybe cause some problems in future code)

or can you explain how your code will change the result? Otherwise this is not an answer, maybe a comment - I am not saying it is wrong to do as suggested, just not an answer

Things I forgot to add to the question:

@user85421 Okay, I understand your point. I suggested getDouble("SUM(Duration") since the next() method moves the ResultSet cursor one step forward from its current position with every iteration, and here, I was not sure about the current position.
So I thought that using getDouble(String columnLabel) would be better, with columnLabel being equal to SUM(Duration), instead of using getDouble(int columnIndex).

columns and rows are independent - next() does not change the column numbering. I agree that using a column name is better than just index number (e.g. query is changed in future and index is changed), but then use a column alias for the column name, SUM(Duration) is not the best name -- but again, my point is: that is not addressing the problem, not answering the question (Why I asked "explain how your code will change the result?")

@user85421 Could the problem be due to the parenthesis used in the column name?
